# How do I move an ImageView in AbsoluteLayout to X Y position

Tags: android, layout, imageview

my main.xml look like this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout
   android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout01"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

   <ImageView
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_x="247dip"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_y="96dip"
      android:id="@+id/Ball"
      android:src="@drawable/ball"/>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

And Java

```
ball = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Ball);
```

How do I do if I whant to move the ball from `x=247dip, y=96dip` to `x=100, y=100` while my app is running?

Answer (score -1):

First set Image's Layout Height and width to Fillparent then use below code

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

        ball.scrollTo(10, 20);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ball.setLeft(10); //this moves view 10 pixel to left
ball.setLeft(-10); //this moves view 10 pixel to right
ball.setRight(10);//this moves view 10 pixel to right
```